How wide should the margin notes area be?
I would like to create a document with a type area according to Van de Graaf. Now I wanted to insert an additional area for margin notes (red area) on the outer margin, but I don't know exactly how wide the area should be and how much space should be left to the edge of the paper. So far the margin note area is 100pt wide, further values can be seen in the illustration (A4 paper):

You could define a grid.
Grid initially defines columns, and that area is a column. Grids also delimit the margin areas.
Common grid numbers for columns are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and probably 6 as the maximum number. Back in the day, when big paper newspapers existed were 8 columns.
The grid does not directly define the column width. You can combine it. For example, on a 6-column grid, you could have a sidebar, 4-column main text, and a sidebar. The margin notes space could be in that sidebar.

Your approach directly gives you width. Go and put some text, define font size, and decide.
If you do not have the proper Hi-Res monitor and specific size, it is a lot better that you print it to see it in real life. Make changes and print again and compare.
